# Twitter typeahead, KnockoutJS not firing onchange/update observable in Chrome/Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm using twitter typeahead together with knockout and I noticed that the observable for the input bind is not updating in chrome/explorer when choosing from typeaheads suggestions. In order for it to update you will have to make a keystroke(like a space) after you have chosen one of the suggestions. Enter/unfocusing the input is not enough(but works in firefox).

Please test it with the following fiddle with chrome/explorer vs firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/s415L158/5/

```
    var viewModel = {
    city:ko.observable()   
}

var cities = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: $.map(["Stockholm","Oslo","Copenhagen"], function(city) { return { value: city }; })
});
cities.initialize();

$('#typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
},
{
name: 'cities',
displayKey: 'value',
source: cities.ttAdapter()
}); 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Update:

To reproduce:

1. Start typing 'S' in the input
2. Select 'Stockholm' from suggestions
3. Unfocus input
4. Observable not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working by adding a custom event that updates the variable on selection of the suggestions, like the following:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
},
{
name: 'cities',
displayKey: 'value',
source: cities.ttAdapter()
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, selection){
viewModel.city(selection.value);
});
```

Comment: Also working if you don't wish to entangle your viewmodel logic with the typeahead plugin is triggering the `change` event manually: `.on('typeahead:selected', function(e, sel) { $(this).change(); });`